# Use a JSON object in different Javascript function

Tags: javascript, json, server-side

I want to send JSON from an API request done on the server to the client side so I can put that information into a Google map.

The request is working. I am getting a JSON object and I can print that to the console but if I try to use the object as a parameter or save it to a variable and print that it returns 'undefined'.

Are either of these things possible?  This is where the server runs the request:

```
router.get("/location/:latitude/:longitude", function(req, res) {
    yelp(req.params.latitude, req.params.longitude);
    res.redirect("/find");
});
```

And this is my function:

```
var request_yelp = function(latitude, longitude) {
var yelp = new Yelp({
    consumer_key: consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: consumer_secret,
    token: token,
    token_secret: token_secret,
});

yelp.search({
    term: 'food',
    ll: latitude + ',' + longitude
})
.then(function (data) {
    /* Convert data to JSON string */
    var str = JSON.stringify(data);
    /* Parse JSON string to JSON Object */
    var obj = JSON.parse(str).businesses;

    return obj;
}) .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

I've tried doing something like this when the server runs the code:

```
var json = yelp(req.params.latitude, req.params.longitude);
```

Ive also tried creating a global variable and assigning it to that before calling it out side the function.  And tried returning the 'data', 'str' and 'obj' variables from the function.  A few other things also but I always get the same 'undefined' response.

The function I was trying to send the object to is just the Google Map's createMarker function which is run on the client side. I haven't got much code to show for that as I haven't been able to retrieve the JSON to begin using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a global object and then assigning your data to it like this:

```
var json = {} || new Object();
json = yelp(req.params.latitude, req.params.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following jquery function to read json response.

```
        $.each(JSON VAR, function(key, values) {
           alert('key=' + key + ', val=' + values);
        });
```